# Implementation of for loop using java8 features

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Can somebody please help me to restructure the following code using java8 features.

Here is my code.

```
private List<CreateChildItemResponse> createChildItems(String[] childUpcNumbers, String[] childItemNbrs,
ItemVo parentItem, UserVo user, boolean isEnableReverseSyncFlag, Integer parentItemNbr, Long parentUpcNbr,int childUpcNbrsize, ItemManagerDelegate managerDelegate) throws NumberFormatException, ValidationException,ChildNotFoundException, ResourceException, ChildItemException {

        List<ItemVo> resultList = new ArrayList<ItemVo>();
        List<CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse> relations = null;
        CreateChildItemResponse response = new CreateChildItemResponse();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < childUpcNumbers.length; i++) {
                // parentItem.setItemNbr(itemNumberList.get(i));
                logger.info("-------Item Nbrs-----" + parentItem.getItemNbr());

                ItemVo child = createItemForMigration(
                        populateChildItemVo(parentItem, getGtin(childUpcNumbers[i]), Integer.valueOf(childItemNbrs[i])),
                        user, isEnableReverseSyncFlag, managerDelegate);// null scales for all except scales integration
                resultList.add(child);

            }
            relations = this.populateAssortmentRelationVo(parentItem.getItemNbr(), resultList);
            response = getSuccessResponse(parentItemNbr, relations, parentUpcNbr);
            // utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.info("Exception occurs while creating child item", e);
            relations = this.populateAssortmentRelationVoForException(e, resultList);
            response = getFailureResponseForException(parentItemNbr, relations, parentUpcNbr, e, resultList.size(),
                    childUpcNbrsize);
            finalResponse.add(response);
            throw new ChildItemException(e.getMessage(), finalResponse, e);
        }
        finalResponse.add(response);
        return finalResponse;
    }
```

here I am calling the below method in the above code

```
relations = this.populateAssortmentRelationVo(parentItem.getItemNbr(), resultList);
```

And the implementation is

```
private List<CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse> populateAssortmentRelationVo(Integer parentItemNumber,
            List<ItemVo> childs) {
        List<CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse> relationList = new ArrayList<CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse>();
        for (ItemVo child : childs) {
            CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse relation = new CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse();
            relation.setItemNbr(child.getItemNbr());
            relation.setUpcNbr(convertUpcToString(child.getEachGtin().getGtinNbr()));
            relation.setStatus("SUCCESS");
            relation.setMessage("");
            relationList.add(relation);
        }
        return relationList;
    }
```

Here I want to take a constructor for the populateAssortmentRelationVo() and how to use stream and mapper inside this.

Answer (score 1):

First declare a mapping function:

```java
private CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse> itemVoToResponse(ItemVo item) {
    CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse response = new CreateChildItemAssortmentResponse();
    response.setItemNbr(item.getItemNbr());
    response.setUpcNbr(convertUpcToString(item.getEachGtin().getGtinNbr()));
    response.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    response.setMessage("");
    return relationList;
}
```

and simply map all the elements of one list into another one:

```java
relations = resultList.stream()
                      .map(this::itemVoToResponse)
                      .collect(toList());
```